# Can I get an id of a campaign from Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to get the id of a campaign.
I've tried this solution, but the point is that I need to get the tracker of the campaing source and by this function I receive this empty.

```
ga(function(tracker) {
console.log(tracker.get('campaignSource'));
 console.log(tracker.get('campaignMedium'));

});
```

This one retuns undefined.

And I've read about these two other options, neither were helpful.

[Get Source and Medium from ga.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752099/get-source-and-medium-from-ga-js)
[How to extract information from Google Click ID (gclid)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576091/how-to-extract-information-from-google-click-id-gclid)